# Delete Accordion item

Tags: jquery, accordion

I tried to create comment box by Jquery Accordion.
But I don't know how to delete clearly item. After delete it content an emplty

Please show me the solutions!

Here is my code:

```
//accordion
$(".questions").accordion({
    event : "click hoverintent",
    header : "> div > h3",
    collapsible : true,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoActivate : true
});

//button remove click handle
$(".bt_remove").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var head = parent.prev('h3');
    parent.add(head).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

//html tructure

```
    <div>
    <h3>Question 2. My Second Question ?</h3>
    <div>
        Second content <input class="bt_remove" type="button" value="remove" />
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Question 3. My Third Question ?</h3>
    <div>
            Third content <input class="bt_remove" type="button" value="remove" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  my understanding is right, You are trying to completely remove the accordion section including its wrapper (which is left behind in your case) You can try this way using **[parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)** till the accordion holder `.questions` and the last one in the collection will be the parent div wrapping the div and h3. This way you can just achieve it with just one selector rather than adding up provious and then finding the parent etc..

```
$(this)
     .parentsUntil('.questions')
     .last()
     .fadeOut('fast', function(){
          $(this).remove();
    });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wdqN/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to delete whole `<div>`

just replace

```
$(this).remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```